# Making my done button reverse segue to the last controller?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segue

I've looked up examples on how to reverse segue in xcode and swift with a storyboard but I can't find an example that pertains to this specific situation where I segue into a navigation controller beforehand. Any pointers?[image: This is the current situation I have where four controllers are segueing in]

Comment: I think you want to use an "unwind segue". Sorry for not giving more info, but it's been a while...and it's Friday and time to go home. :-p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use navigation controller, you can use

```
self.navigationcontroller?.popviewcontroller(animation: true)
```

Please try this

Answer (score 1):

It is the same as an ordinary unwind segue.

In your source view controller add this action

```
@IBAction func unwindToMain(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {}
```

And from your destination view (which is titled Action) connect your button to the **Exit**.

Hope this helps :)